# Weird, but true: iPhone earphones stop working when I walk into a particular room

Tags: iphone, audio, ear-phones

When I walk into our master bedroom, about half the time, my earphones on my iPhone stop working.  That is, the podcast continues to play (I'm usually using Castro, but it's hard to imagine that's the issue), but I'm getting no sound from the earphones.

It's not the particular phone. It happened with my previous phone (an iPhone 5) and it's happens with my new iPhone SE.

It's not the earphones. I've had this problem with the stock ph earphones nes, a cheap pair of drugstore earphones, and pair of nice $40 third-party earphones.

It's not what I'm physically doing. I keep the phone in my left pocket and on bud in my right ear. But I can do all kinds of activities -- cleaning, laundry, yardwork, whatever -- without this happening.

It feels like there's something about the room itself that causes this to happen. If it happens, it usually happens as soon as I walk through the door of the bedroom.

Comment: What happens if you play from the iPhone speaker, with no earphones plugged in?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a Bluetooth headphones or speaker in your master bedroom that you've paired to your phone?  Perhaps the phone's audio output is switching over to Bluetooth when it's within range.

Comment: I think this is the right answer.  I have a bluetooth earphone that I leave in the bedroom and it's typically on. I'll test it, but I bet this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you streaming this podcast?  It sounds like it.    You're probably losing your wifi connection.

Comment: It's an issue with downloaded podcasts as well as streaming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not a hardware issue. Wired headsets, like the iPhone earbuds, wouldn't be affected by location. If they were, you'd also have issue with your phone itself. Chances are, without any additional information to go off of, I'd say that if you're streaming then you WiFi or Network connection in your bedroom is iffy.

If you haven't done so already, reset your wireless router. If you aren't using WiFi, try restarting your phone to reset your network connection.